# Button Hide & Show only on first row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my userlist generated with a `for` loop with the same ID and function for all the save button. The Button hide & show is only working in the 1st row.

```
@foreach (var usr in (List<RegistrationResponsive.Models.RegistrationModels>)ViewData["UsersList"])
{
    <td>
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = "Active",
                             Value = "Active"
                         });
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = "In Active",
                             Value = "InActive"
                         });
        }

        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => @usr.Status, listItems, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "OFF", @id = "drpDwn", onchange = "MyFunction()" })
        <td id="btn" style="display:none">
            <button type="submit" style="float:right" onclick="Save('@usr.ID')" ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-primary active pull-right">Save</button>
        <td>
        </td>
   </tr>
}
```

And this is the JS function that I use to show/hide the button:

```
function MyFunction() {
    if ($('#drpDwn').val() == "Active") {
        $('#btn').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#btn').show();
    }
}
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="table-responsive container">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped webgrid-table">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone No.</th>
                <th>Country&nbsp;Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Sanju
                </td>
                <td>
                    +91XXXXXXXXXX
                </td>
                <td>
                    India
                </td>
                <td>
                    Female
                </td>
                <td>


                    <select autocomplete="OFF" class="form-control" id="drpDwn" name="usr.Status" onchange="MyFunction()"><option value="Active">Active</option>
<option value="InActive">In Active</option>
</select>
                <td id="btn" style="display:none">
                    <button type="submit" style="float:right" onclick="Save('5sYRctjnzg')" ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-primary active pull-right">Save</button>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Satheesh
                </td>
                <td>
                    +91XXXXXXXXXX
                </td>
                <td>
                    India
                </td>
                <td>
                    Male
                </td>
                <td>


                    <select autocomplete="OFF" class="form-control" id="drpDwn" name="usr.Status" onchange="MyFunction()"><option value="Active">Active</option>
<option value="InActive">In Active</option>
</select>
                <td id="btn" style="display:none">
                    <button type="submit" style="float:right" onclick="Save('u421Z4VIyV')" ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-primary active pull-right">Save</button>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Prabhu
                </td>
                <td>
                    +91XXXXXXXXXX
                </td>
                <td>
                    India
                </td>
                <td>
                    Male
                </td>
                <td>


                    <select autocomplete="OFF" class="form-control" id="drpDwn" name="usr.Status" onchange="MyFunction()"><option value="Active">Active</option>
<option value="InActive">In Active</option>
</select>
                <td id="btn" style="display:none">
                    <button type="submit" style="float:right" onclick="Save('H8FBLiC8GO')" ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-primary active pull-right">Save</button>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- removed more rows from here -->

        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: change id to class then it would work fine.

Comment: Hi Jai thank you for the reply I have tried using class then also the same issue arise

Comment: ID should be unique on page.

Comment: @Anbarasi you need to change ids to class names on each element in the loop, like `td id="btn"` to `td class="btn"` and use the class name in js `$('.btn')`.

Comment: @Anbarasi better to post your generated markup instead of this aspx code. That would be much easier to provide solution.

Comment: @Jai Sorry to ask what you are mean by generated markup

Comment: The code that you are showing is not plain HTML, it is ASP.Net. Jai wants the code that you see when you view the source in the browsers (the generated code)

Comment: Apart from that, Jai is correct. The problem is that you have multiple elements with the same id. The browser doesn't know which one you are referring to and only applies the changes to the first one that it finds (the first row)

Comment: @jai I have Posted my generated markup can you explore

Comment: Is that real data from real people?

Comment: One sec, I'll edit the question. You should not publish people's phone numbers without their permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.selectOption').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Active") {
            $(this).parents('.parent').children('.subButton').hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents('.parent').children('.subButton').show();
        }
    });
});

@foreach (var usr in (List<RegistrationResponsive.Models.RegistrationModels>)ViewData["UsersList"])
{
    <tr class="parent">
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Active",
                Value = "Active"
            });
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "In Active",
                Value = "InActive"
            });
        }
        <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => @usr.Status, listItems, new { @class = "form-control selectOption", @autocomplete = "OFF", @id = "drpDwn"" })
        </td>
        <td id="btn" class="subButton" style="display:none">
            <button type="submit" style="float:right" onclick="Save('@usr.ID')" ng-hide="false" class="btn btn-primary active pull-right">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @ sachinK Thank you for your reply. this snippet arise Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in my console

Comment: can you please show your final render HTML on page?

Comment: This looks like it should work fine (even with multiple elements with the same id that should be avoided). The `toLowerCase` error comes from somewhere different in the code, and as Sachink says, it's impossible to know without the related code.

Comment: @SachinK I am using pagination for the grid, In first page it working fine but in second page it doesn't work. It doesn't trigger the event. I have Used dataTable for sorting,Paging and Searching

Comment: @Anbarasi, I think after sorting, paging and searching the table will get refresh. you need to reinitialize the event. Now we initialize with page ready. The class of an element does not change the events bound to it. Events are bound to the element, not the class.